# Backbone Collection - Constructor

Tags: backbone.js

I am passing an array to new collection. Is it possible to filter the array by passing second parameter and check on the attr of the object in the array and create collection only if it pass the filter test.

```
collection = new Backbone.Collection([{name:'xy',age:24},{name:'y',age:35}])
```

Can I create a collection only for the object less than 30 years.

Comment: Can you add some code? It is hard to follow what are you trying to achieve based on your description...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [_.filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) on your array before passing into the collection

```
collection = new Backbone.Collection(
     _.filter([{name:'xy',age:24},{name:'y',age:35}], 
              function(item) { return item.age < 30; }));
```

Or you can move your custom filtering logic into your collection `initialize` where you will get the `models` array what you can modify/filter

```
var Under30 = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        for(var i = models.length - 1; i > 0; i-- ){
            if (models[i].age > 30){
                models.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    }
});

var collection = new Under30([{name:'xy',age:24}, {name:'y',age:35}]);
console.log(collection.models.length); // will be 1
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLTNK/).

You can extend this with supplying the filter predicate in the options parameter

```
var FilteredCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        initialize: function(models, options) {
            for(var i = models.length - 1; i > 0; i-- ){
                if (options.filter && options.filter(models[i])){
                    models.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And use it with

```
var collection = new FilteredCollection(
      [{name:'xy',age:24}, {name:'y',age:35}], 
      {
          filter: function(item) { 
              return item.age > 30; 
          }
      }
);
console.log(collection.models.length); // will be 1
```

Comment: I would be passing array from no of places..I would like the collection to take care of it..not sure may be in the constructor before creating the collection

Comment: @cool you can add this custom filtering into your collection initialize method. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I think I can live with splice in the intialiization to remove the unnesecssary models. I could use a filtered function but this would be  a difficult to code maintain compared to being in the validation of the collection / intialization.. But there is still the question can we add validation within colleciton /model during create/constructor

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

You're interested in validation before creating the collection, just like the answer before - we'll create a function that lets you reuse that strategy to validate any collection based on a condition you'd like.

```
//A collection that validates the correctness of the given elements
// based on a predicate (condition). If the items do not _all_ pass
// the condition - the collection will not be created and an error will
// be thrown.
function validatingCollection(predicate){
    return function(arr){
        //first we assert an array is passed if it's possible to assert
        if(Array.isArray && !Array.isArray(arr)){
            throw new Error("Can only pass array to filteredCollection");
        }
        //for older browsers - use _.every 
        // now we validate they all pass the condition
        if(!arr.every(predicate){
            throw new Error("Validation error, not all elements pass");
        }
        //they all pass, create the collection
        return new Backbone.Collection(arr);
    };
};
```

Now, we can create such a collection, that validates that every element has age of at least 30:

```
var ageValidated = validatedCollection(function(obj){ return obj.age < 30; });
//create a new age validatedcollection
try{
    var collection = new ageValidated([{name:'xy',age:24},{name:'y',age:35}]); 
}catch(e){
    // the above throws an error because of the object with age 24
}
//however - this works, and creates a new collection
var collection = new ageValidated([{name:'xy',age:32},{name:'y',age:35}]);
```

---

If you just want to filter the elements you don't like - instead of throwing an error if not all of them pass validation you can do something like this :

```
collection = new Backbone.Collection([{name:'xy',age:24},
                                      {name:'y',age:35}].filter(function(obj){
                                          return obj.age < 30;
                                      });
```

Alternatively, you can create your own filtered collection constructor for reuse as such

```
function filteredCollection(predicate){
    return function(arr){
        //first we assert an array is passed if it's possible to assert
        if(Array.isArray && !Array.isArray(arr)){
            throw new Error("Can only pass array to filteredCollection");
        }
        return new Backbone.Collection(arr.filter(predicate));
    };
};
```

Which lets us do :

```
var ageFilter = filteredCollection(function(obj){ return obj.age < 30; });
    //create a new age collection
var collection = new ageFilter([{name:'xy',age:24},{name:'y',age:35}]);
```

The other answer suggests `_.filter` over the native Array.filter , this might be beneficial if you have to support old browsers.

Comment: thanks..My Question would be can there be validation in collection construction before it creates ...

Comment: @coool I've updated my solution with emphasis on code reuse. Moreover, you might want to consider putting the objects themselves in a `Backbone.Model` and putting the validation on the model (Maybe having a `Person` model and then an `OlderPerson` model and handling validation there, alternatively - not using Backbone all together depending on what you want to accomplish)